# Unreliable results of a query

Tags: visual-foxpro

I need to get sales figures from open orders, sorted by code. The items are separated in the stock table by lot number (for traceability reasons) but the lot numbers do not appear in the orders table. The only link between the 2 tables is the part number.

When my query

SELECT code, SUM(qty*price) AS Sales 
    FROM orders INNER JOIN stock ON orders.partno = stock.partno 
    GROUP BY code

started returning strange results (very high sales figures for a given code), I changed it to

SELECT DISITNCT orders.partno, stock.lot, stock.code 
    FROM orders INNER JOIN stock ON orders.partno = stock.partno

and noticed that if several lots of a given part are in stock they are all returned

Part1   LotA    code

Part1   LotB    code

Part1   LotC    code

which means that if a customer orders 300 units of Part1, my query returns 900 and my sales figure is multiplied by 3.

How can I work around that?

It must be noted that I do not work from a database but from a group of tables, the structures of which can sometimes be whimsical.

Comment: Unfortunately with a design like this you can't group your sales by code.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use table.column or alias.column reference when writing queries.  As your question stands, we do not know which table the PRICE comes from... the parts table or the lots table.  If you are dealing with inventory tracking such as FIFO or LIFO method accounting, you must have an association to the lot table for inventory being tracked/sold.

Now, why are you getting large numbers?  That is because of a Cartesian result.  If you are not familiar with that, for each record in one table joined to another, it is returning however many matches.

So, if you have an order of one line item, there is only one line item in a products available table.  So this is simple 1:1 ratio.  Now, you have your STOCK table that can have multiple records for the exact same part number.  You are now returning the same original order line item for EACH LOT ENTRY in the Stock table.  So now, for your 1 item, you are getting 3 lots  (1:3 result).

I know this is important from a cost-of-goods sold basis, hence your need to know which "lot" it is joined to so you only get that one specific record for proper pricing.

If however, you do have a generic product table of everything you sell, and that table has a generic common price no matter which "lot" was used for the sale, I would join to that table instead for your report.  But you will still have the accounting issue of inventory, cost-of-goods, etc.